# django rest framwork - delete object, its ManyToMany fields and objects with foreign keys to it

Tags: model, django-rest-framework, relation, http-delete, manytomanyfield

**Here are my models:**

```
class Ride(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='rides_as_driver')
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    leaving_time=models.TimeField()
    leaving_date=models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    num_of_spots=models.IntegerField()
    passengers=models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name="rides_as_passenger")
    mid_destinations = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')


class PendingRequest(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='driver_pending_requests')
    passenger = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='passenger_pending_requests')
    ride = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
```

As you can see - I have a **Ride** model with `ManyToMany` field to `auth.user` (passengers), `ForeginKey` to `auth.user` (driver), and **also** a **PendingRequest** model which has a `ForeginKey` field to **Ride**.

Now, I want to to be able to delete a Ride object, have a custom code after the delete, and make sure that other models update accordingly.

For example, if I delete a Ride -> I want to have a custom code (send notification to passengers) -> and then delete the entries in the **passenger table** that have the **deleted ride id** in their `ride` field, and also the **PendingRequest** entries which have the **deleted ride id**.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

All you describe it business logic. You should have a function for that, override the `destroy` member - if you're using `ViewSet` - and call the business function from it.

Edit:
corrected delete to destroy.

destroy signature is:
`destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: thanks. the delete method name to override is just 'def delete'?

Comment: My bad, it's destroy. Editing the response.

Comment: thanks. one weird thing that is happening is , without the overriding - when I do DELETE rides/139/ I get a Not Found 404 response. I check in the database and there is a ride with the id of 139. why is that?